# VS Webpack Task Runner - how to bind run tasks to Debug and Release

Tags: visual-studio, webpack

In the Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer, I can bind 'Run - Development' to 'After Build' and this works very well. I can also bind 'Run - Production' to 'After Build' and this will also work.

What I want to be able to do, is have 'Run - Development' execute when I'm in Debug mode, and have 'Run - Production' execute when I'm in Release mode.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Although the response from @VinTem below is marked as the answer I would prefer to have an integrated solution in the Task Runner itself. There really needs to be some way to setup bindings that pertain to Debug, Release, or any other configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [nuget package that you can install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Npm/) that allows you to run npm commands.

Then you can add two different commands to your `package.json` file, like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack": "webpack",
  "webpack-prd": "webpack -p"
},
```

After having the nuget package installed you edit your .csproj file to run the npm commands configured. Here's how I did:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <NpmCommand>run webpack</NpmCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <NpmCommand>run webpack-prd</NpmCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
```